# Obj-C: How can I use my retrieved keyboard height inside of animateTextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use the height of my keyboard (which I grab in keyboardWillChange 'keyHeight')  inside of my animateTextView so that I can make it the  movementDistance. How can I grab this value? Seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to do it...

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil]; 

    CGFloat keyHeight = keyboardRect.size.height;
    NSLog(@"THIS IS THE HEIGHT %f", keyHeight);

}

- (void) animateTextView:(BOOL) up
{

    const int movementDistance = 100;
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f;
    int movement= movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);
    NSLog(@"%d",movement);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

    self.upView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.upView.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(afterAnimationStops)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private property by adding the private category before the implementation of the ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController()
@property(nonatomic, assign) CGFloat keyboardHeight;
@end

@implementation ViewController
....
```

Then assign the height value to it inside the keyboardWillChange:

```
self.keyboardHeight = keyboardRect.size.height;
```

And then use it inside the animateTextView:

```
CGFloat movementDistance = self.keyboardHeight;
```